# MvxRecyclerView with button in each row

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am making an Android application with Xamarin.Android and MvvmCross. I have a `MvxRecyclerView`:

```
<MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/auto_complete_search_item"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource SearchAutoCompleteItems; ItemClick SearchAutoCompleteItemClick" />
```

And my `auto_complete_search_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/auto_complete_search_item_height"
android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_large"
        local:MvxBind="Text Title" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_large"
        local:MvxBind="Text Category" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fill_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        local:MvxLang="Text fa-arrow-up"
        local:MvxBind="Style ., Converter=String,     ConverterParameter=fonts/fontawesome.ttf" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My click handler `ItemClick SearchAutoCompleteItemClick` works, but I need to handle the click event for when the user clicks on my `fill_button` separately. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using a custom `MvxRecyclerView` and custom `MvxRecyclerAdapter`:

```
public class TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView : MvxRecyclerView
{
    private ICommand _itemClickPiece1;
    private ICommand _itemClickPiece2;

    public ICommand ItemClickPiece1
    {
        get { return _itemClickPiece1; }
        set
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(_itemClickPiece1, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            _itemClickPiece1 = value;
        }
    }

    public ICommand ItemClickPiece2
    {
        get { return _itemClickPiece2; }
        set
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(_itemClickPiece2, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            _itemClickPiece2 = value;
        }
    }

    public TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView(Context context, IAttributeSet attr) : base(context, attr)
    {
    }

    public TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }
}

public class TwoPieceMvxRecyclerAdapter : MvxRecyclerAdapter, IOnClickListener
{
    public TwoPieceMvxRecyclerAdapter(IMvxAndroidBindingContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    public TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView { get; set; }

    protected override Android.Views.View InflateViewForHolder(Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, int viewType, MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var view = base.InflateViewForHolder(parent, viewType, bindingContext);

        var clickablePiece1 = view.FindViewById<View>(Resource.Id.clickable_piece1);
        var clickablePiece2 = view.FindViewById<View>(Resource.Id.clickable_piece2);

        clickablePiece1.SetOnClickListener(this);
        clickablePiece2.SetOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        var viewHolder = this.TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView.FindContainingViewHolder(v);

        var item = GetItem(viewHolder.LayoutPosition); // What different is viewHolder.AdapterPosition? I tested it with 100 items and it's always the same, but I'm not sure if this will never break...

        if (v.Id == Resource.Id.clickable_piece1)
        {
                TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView.ItemClickPiece1.Execute(item);
        }
        else if (v.Id == Resource.Id.clickable_piece2)
        {
                TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView.ItemClickPiece2.Execute(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the containing activity (or fragment):

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_search);

    var r = FindViewById<TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.my_twopiecemvxrecyclerview);
    var adapter = new TwoPieceMvxRecyclerAdapter(((IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext));
    adapter.TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView = r;
    r.Adapter = adapter;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<My.Namespace.TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_twopiecemvxrecyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/my_two_piece_layout"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MyItems; ItemClickPiece1 MyItemClick1; ItemClickPiece2 MyItemClick2" />
```

`my_two_piece_layout.xml` needs to have views with ids `clickable_piece1` and `clickable_piece2`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second binding to the `TextView`. That will bind a `Click` event to a command you will define in the `SearchAutoCompleteItem` type (the command will be declared on the level of the individual item).

```
local:MvxBind="Click FillCommand; Style ., Converter=String, ConverterParameter=fonts/fontawesome.ttf"
```

Comment: That would also trigger the click event for the entire row.