# Custom MvxRecyclerAdapter

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross in my Xamarin.Android application. I want to make my own custom `MvxRecyclerAdapter` so that I can have multiple buttons in each row of the `MvxRecyclerView`. Here is my custom `MvxRecyclerView`:

```
public class TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView : MvxRecyclerView
{
    private bool _initialized;

    public TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView(Context context, IAttributeSet attr) : base(context, attr)
    {

    }

    public override Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView.Adapter GetAdapter()
    {
        if(!_initialized)
        {
            SetAdapter(new TwoPieceMvxRecyclerAdapter());
            _initialized = true;
        }

        return base.GetAdapter();
    }
}
```

And here is my custom `MvxRecyclerAdapter`:

```
public class TwoPieceMvxRecyclerAdapter : MvxRecyclerAdapter, IOnClickListener
{
    private ICommand _itemClickPiece1;
    private ICommand _itemClickPiece2;

    private View _clickablePiece1;
    private View _clickablePiece2;

    public TwoPieceMvxRecyclerAdapter()
    {
    }

    public ICommand ItemClickPiece1
    {
        get { return _itemClickPiece1; }
        set
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(_itemClickPiece1, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            _itemClickPiece1 = value;
        }
    }

    public ICommand ItemClickPiece2
    {
        get { return _itemClickPiece2; }
        set
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(_itemClickPiece2, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            _itemClickPiece2 = value;
        }
    }

    protected override Android.Views.View InflateViewForHolder(Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, int viewType, MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var view = base.InflateViewForHolder(parent, viewType, bindingContext);

        _clickablePiece1 = view.FindViewById<View>(Resource.Id.clickable_piece1);
        _clickablePiece2 = view.FindViewById<View>(Resource.Id.clickable_piece2);

        _clickablePiece1.SetOnClickListener(this);
        _clickablePiece2.SetOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        if (v == _clickablePiece1)
        {
            ItemClickPiece1.Execute(null);
        }
        else if (v == _clickablePiece2)
        {
            ItemClickPiece2.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the application I get this error:

> Could not activate JNI Handle 0xbfd00978 (key_handle 0x6e44919) of
>   Java type
>   'md5bd77c484e80df14e69d8c5ab04394fe0/TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView' as
>   managed type
>   'AzzimovMobile.Droid.Components.TwoPieceMvxRecycler.TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView'.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: If you wan't to use single
>   item-template RecyclerView Adapter you can't change
>   it'sIMvxTemplateSelector to anything other than
>   MvxDefaultTemplateSelector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a constructor on your RecyclerView:

```
public TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer): base(javaReference, transfer)
{
}
```

Also be aware you don't need to use a custom RecyclerView to change its Adapter. You can just grab the RecyclerView instance on your .cs view and set the adapter from there. Something like this should work:

```
public class MyView: MvxFragment<MyViewModel>
{
    //...

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        // ...

        var recycler = view.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recycler);
        recycler.Adapter = new TwoPieceMvxRecyclerAdapter(((IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext);

        // you can even set a TemplateSelector here!
        recycler.ItemTemplateSelector = new MyTemplateSelector();
        // ...

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to keep the `TwoPieceMvxRecyclerView` so the bindings will work in the xml. I put the full solution to what I was doing over here as the accepted answer for anyone who wants to see it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48713243/1136506